# Different results when executing the SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the program there is a part of the code, which executes the query:

```
string SPROC = "#Some MSSQL Query#";
comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
comm.CommandText = SPROC;
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = PARAM1;
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)).Value = PARAM2;
comm.CommandTimeout = CurrentSettings.SQLTimeout;

conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
DataSet TempDS = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(TempDS);
```

The dataset (`TempDS`) table is supposed to have around 20000 records (row count) but inside the program it is saying only 20 records while in debugging mode.

I ran the script separately on the same database table, which is being used in the SQL Server connection string, but in SQL Server Management Studio, it returned 20000 records as it is supposed to do.

The script looks some what like:

```
Select 
    [Table1].Column1,[Table2].Column1 
From 
    [Table1]
Inner Join 
    [Table2] on ([Table2].Column1 = [Table1].Column2)
Where 
    [Table2].Column1 = @Parameter1 
    and ([Table1].Column1 in (Select * from dbo.Split(@Parameter2,','))
```

It is the same script text, which the code executes as well.

Does anybody have any idea why the program code is only bringing back part of the record whereas the script in SQL Server Management Studio returns all the records?

P.S. I have also checked the SQLTimeOut and it is set to 240, so more than enough time to return the records properly. And @Parameter1 and @Parameter2 are string variables.

```
string PARAM1 = "Random1"; //in C#
string PARAM2 = "Random2,Random3,Random4,Random5"; //in C#
@Parameter1 = PARAM1
@Parameter2 = PARAM2
```

Comment: First use profiler to look at the query being sent from your application to SQL and verify it is the query you expect it to be.

Comment: Check you are actually using the same database when debugging.

Comment: Have you tried running the stored procedure directly on SQL directly by Right clicking the Stored procedure and choosing "execute"?  If so, make sure you are passing in the same parameter values that your program is

Comment: Yup, all of those are exact same one. Right query and right database. This is the first time I came across such a weird problem.

Comment: Should not `CommandType` here be StoredProcedure and not Text?  Is that a stored procedure name? (SPROC) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DiscipleMichael Yes. I executed the StoredProcedure by pressing the execute option as well as I have pasted the script and executing it by replcaing the Parameters with actual string, which it is supposed to have in the code.

Comment: Debug and break right before `conn.Open()` check comm.Parameters["@Parameter1"] and comm.Parameters["@Parameter2"]

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  I missed that... I glanced over it, but yeah this looks like a Stored Proc (ie. SPROC variable name).

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss  SPROC is actually the Text of the Stored Procedure, which is there in the database. All our stored procedures are managed by a DLL, which accumulates all the SPs and builds them inside the DLL. I have checked the SP. The text is exactly the same, noting unusual or out of ordinary. It's a ditto copy. So although it seems like a SP but it is actually a script text, which is fetched from the DLL itself.

Comment: ok SO it is NOT a stored procedure it is some text pushed into that variable - regardless of the source, debug should show that text you have here...(the procedure text)

Comment: Okay, if that's the case, then you can break after the params are set and check the value of comm.CommandText.  Then you can paste into SQL and see if you get same result.

Comment: yes. thats how I executed the text on the management server by copying the text thru the debugging mode and also comparing it with the SP stored on the server database.

Comment: hmm... security issues from 1 of the two tables?

Comment: Paste the parameters values here into the question from the debug

Comment: Have you run a profiler trace to see what the actual query is being executed on your sql server? You should start there.

Comment: Something like?  Is there anything non-deterministic going on?  Are you running under the same credentials (authority)?

Comment: PARAM@ value exceeds 20 - see your parameter split - this is the reason

Comment: Yes, I ran the Profiler as well and double checked. Although I do have to admit that the credentials (authority) to execute the query from the program and on SQL Management server are different, but why would that cause the problem when the same thing doesnt cause any issue when other SPs or scripts are being executed?? (Parameter values are added in the code as well now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of string exceeds the parameter length in the C#

```
string PARAM2 = "Random2,Random3,Random4,Random5"; //in C#

comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Parameter2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)).Value = PARAM2;
```

so you need to allocate more length here

Try using AddWithValue : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

NOTE: IF you do this, also be aware of the SPLIT function capacity of the input; it might need to be adjusted to some large value - search for some split functions that take large inputs

Comment: OP should have caught this in the profiler trace though.

Comment: Frankly I have made this mistake; and caught it sometimes a second set of eyes is very productive.  Experience and making mistakes and fixing them has use.